# Different images in different cells of tableViewController are not working properly

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have made a `tableViewController`. I want to give different images to the 1st and 7th index cell. This is a code snippet inside my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method. It initializes the cells properly in the beginning but when I scroll up and down several times then it also starts to give the "button4.png" in the accessory view of other cells.

```
                UIImage *indicatorImage;
            if(indexPath.row==0||indexPath.row==6)
            {
                indicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button4.png"];
            }
            else
            {
                indicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img-arrow.png"];
            }      

        cell.accessoryView =
        [[UIImageView alloc]
          initWithImage:indicatorImage];
```

What can be the possible reason for this?

The complete code of the function is a little messy, but I am posting it here:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    selection=self.tabBarController.selectedIndex;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UILabel *topLabel;

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        UIImage *indicatorImage;



        if(indexPath.row==0||indexPath.row==6)
        {
            indicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button4.png"];
        }
        else
        {
            indicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img-arrow.png"];
        }      

    cell.accessoryView =
    [[UIImageView alloc]
      initWithImage:indicatorImage];

        cell.accessoryView =
        [[UIImageView alloc]
          initWithImage:indicatorImage];
        const CGFloat LABEL_HEIGHT = 20;



        topLabel =
        [[UILabel alloc]
          initWithFrame:
          CGRectMake(
                     2.0 * cell.indentationWidth,
                     0.5 * (tableView.rowHeight - 2 * LABEL_HEIGHT),
                     tableView.bounds.size.width -
                     4.0 * cell.indentationWidth
                     - indicatorImage.size.width,
                     LABEL_HEIGHT)];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:topLabel];

        topLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        topLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        topLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
        topLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
        topLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:0.9 alpha:1.0];
        topLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont labelFontSize]];

        topLabel.tag=10;
        cell.backgroundView =
        [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView =
        [[UIImageView alloc] init];

    }
}
else
{
    topLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
}

UIImage *rowBackground;
UIImage *selectionBackground;


rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topAndBottomRow.png"];
selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topAndBottomRowSelected.png"];


    if(indexPath.row==0||indexPath.row==6)
    {

        rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topAndBottomRowSelected.png"];
        selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topAndBottomRowSelected.png"];

        topLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
        topLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:0.9 alpha:1.0];
        topLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
    }


((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image = rowBackground;
((UIImageView *)cell.selectedBackgroundView).image = selectionBackground;


NSString *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
NSString *str=[object description];
topLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"         %@",str];

return cell;
```

}

Comment: Can you please post your whole cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: I have added my whole code of the function in the question. Please suggest some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting this image in your `if (cell == nil) ...` block in which you create and configure the cell. But you need to move this image setting outside of that `if` block because if the cell is being reused (ie you don't have to `alloc` and `init`), the old image will be reused. You should review anything inside that `if` statement for things that should change cell-by-cell, and move that outside of the `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

When scrolling messes you up like this, it suggests that you're not completely initializing the contents of a **REUSED** UITableViewCell.  While your code snippet says you do set it to something -- your result suggests that you aren't.  You can look for that.

For instance, try setting the accessoryView to nil immediately after getting the cell and see if the problem goes away.